# Order of PHP query insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that adds data into my SQL table:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (first_name, last_name, email) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')
```

However, doing this inserts the data "backwards" into the table (i.e. the first entry will be the last in the table).  Is there a way to insert the data into the last position of the given table?

Comment: You can select them after backward... and the the last will be the first.

Comment: If you define a primary key with auto increment in your table it should work whenever you insert a data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database tables do not have an inherit order. When you query a table without explicitly specifying an `order by` clause there's no guarantee on the returned order, so there's no concept of data being inserted in a certain order or not - just explicitly specify what order you want it selected.

Comment: So if my query is `SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM user_data`, I'd add `ORDER BY date, date, date` to the query?  (assuming I have another column called `date`)

Comment: @Firedrake969 You `order by` a **column** not a row - I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Oops, I meant having another column called date - my bad.  Fixed.

Comment: @Firedrake969 in that case, you only need to specify it once - `SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM user_date ORDER BY date`.

Comment: To add the date value to the appropriate column, would I add `CURDATE()` or `GETDATE()` after `'$email'` (from the query in my original question)?

Comment: @Firedrake969 in [tag:mysql] it's indeed `CURDATE()` (or `CURRENT_DATE()`). `GETDATE()` is a [tag:sql-server] function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify at which position your records get written. You may do an `order by` in the select statement, and you may use [`myismchk`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisamchk-other-options.html#option_myisamchk_sort-records) with option `--sort-records` to do the ordering afterwards.